# How can I register a surrogate for a generic class in protobuff-net?

Tags: generics, protobuf-net

I have a generic class, `PropertyCollection<TKey>`. Because it contains a collection with values of object type, I have to use a surrogate. The trick is, I want to do this once for all possible types passed in `TKey`.

I have no problem doing this for a single type. If I want to use the surrogate when `TKey` is a `MyEnum`, I use the code block below and it works fine.

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default
                .Add(typeof(PropertyCollection<MyEnum>), false)
                .SetSurrogate(typeof(PropertyCollectionSurrogate<MyEnum>));
```

My challenge is getting it to work with *all* values of `TKey`. I tried adding the type in a method decorated with the `[OnSerializing]` attribute, but this doesn't work because a serializer is already created.

I realize that each `TKey` is essentially a different method, so maybe I'm stuck. 
Is there a way to register the surrogate using an attribute, that might follow the class around? Or can I effectively "roll my own" serialization using the `[OnSerializing]` and `[OnDeserializing]` attributes?

Anything would be really appreciated here!